# Usage of .net ajax toolkit and others

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have just started to use Ajax/ws and i have faced this question:

Why do i have to use Microsoft ajax tool kit if Microsoft started to implement Jquery/java-script

What are the benefits of each one? (is Microsoft still support ajax tool?)

I know that Java-script is a client side language and rhat through several methods i can use java-script to communicate with the server.

Microsoft ajax tool kit contains a lot of plugins which i can download, and one example

Microsoft ajax -> date calendar VS Jquery-> datepicker.

Maybe i am missing something, what are the benefits of using Script manager -> Update panel?

Which method is the "right" one?

I know that everyone should explore and use the one they most convenient with.

But for one who is "lack" of experiences in that area,

where is the best place to start?

appreciate any "direction" and some theory regarding this subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some answers to your questions:

- Microsoft ajax control toolkit is obsolete. It's heavy, difficult to extend, only used for Web Form, sometimes cause weird issues
- Microsoft has not developed jquery. They just supported JQuery in Visual Studio. I can assure you once you master JQuery(not so difficult and very easy to start), you'll see that you never need something like Ajax control toolkit or Telerik. You can do or customize yourself most of everything on the client side.
- If you're new to ASP.Net and Ajax, then Web Form, Script manager and Update panel may be a quick way to achieve the result. But for the long run, I think you should learn MVC, JQuery, KnockoutJs. They are hot now :-)

Comment: Thanks.. very informative answer, Microsoft ajax control toolkit is still supported by Microsoft? i heard that this technology is an "old" one. and soon Microsoft will not support it anymore, instead they will package Jquery in the follow frameworks. is this true? if so there is no point to study this technology just to know that it is there..

Comment: I am not sure if MS has some plans with JQuery but there's tons of JQuery plugins/controls out there. Just google what you need!

Comment: ok, so from my understanding i should focus on using jquery for ajax requests, and should only know the MS ajax control toolkit is there. i got it right?

Comment: yeah, Jquery is a good way to start. Every web developers should know it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to not bother with Microsoft Ajax Toolkit. I believe this is old school now. Use jquery, jquery ui or any other client side javascript toolkit such as dojo, kendoui etc and integrate it with you ASP.Net application. This would provide you maximum flexibility.

What MS AJAX toolkit provide is a set of controls on server side which allow easy drag and drop into form designer. These controls then generate some client side html + javascript to enable all the slick behaviour as it is with other ASP.Net server control.

If i may suggest start looking into ASP.Net MVC. You would not regret.